# Term for Tetrahedron with Three Right Angles at a Point

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

Is there a name for the tetrahedron/pyramid (four vertices, four triangular faces, six edges) where three edges meet orthogonally at a point? Three of the faces are right triangles.

Another description: taking $\vec e_1,\vec e_2,\vec e_3$ as the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, the vertices are $\vec 0,c_1\vec e_1,c_2\vec e_2,c_3\vec e_3$. The faces are composed of the coordinate planes with the plane $x/c_1 + y/c_2 + z/c_3 = 1$.

Comment: In Coxeter's book it is called an orthoscheme.

Comment: I've also seen this figure just called a 'right tetrahedron', by analogy with 'right triangle', and that's probably the first name that I would use for it in informal math writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Wolfram's Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrirectangularTetrahedron.html), it's called a *trirectangular* tetrahedron.

Answer (score 2):

A *right-cornered* tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

A common name is *rectangular tetrahedron*.

Answer (score 1):

Any solid polytope of the form $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{a_i} \leq 1$, where $a_i > 0$ is called a *solid, orthotopal, simplicial $n$-polytope* and can also be written as the convex hull $\mathbf{conv} \{ \mathbf{0}, a_1 \mathbf{e}_1, \dots, a_n \mathbf{e}_n \}$. For $n = 3$, it is called a *solid trirectangular tetrahedron*. If you mean the boundary complex, then simply *trirectangular tetrahedron* is fine.